# Log In With Paypal button doesn't redirect on login

Tags: javascript, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to implement the Paypal login button seen here -> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/integrate/generate-button/. After logging in and clicking "Agree and Connect", however, I get the error "Something went wrong on our end."
I use the same client ID and return URL in my script as on the Paypal developer sandbox account page. The return URL is fully functional as well. I tried both the sandbox and live version but get the same error. Does anyone know the fix to this?I don't get any error logs or API call logs in my developer account for these. For greater context, my goal is just to validate a user is linking a valid Paypal account to my website.